# What is the meaning of the "return" tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

There are 1007 questions tagged [return](/questions/tagged/return), which seem not related to each other.

I guess that in some of them, the tag is referring to the `return` statement used in some languages. If that is the case, do we need that tag? What meaning does it add to the question?

Comment: Time for cleanup...

Comment: Definitely a meta-use tag. Signal the dragon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a legitimate reason for the [return](/questions/tagged/return) to be burninated, surely that would mean that

- [break](/questions/tagged/break) (274)
- [continue](/questions/tagged/continue) (81)
- [exit](/questions/tagged/exit) (406)
- [start](/questions/tagged/start) (290)
- [stop](/questions/tagged/stop) (374)
- etc...

Should be too?  I'm not saying that I support it - I'm just saying that there are so many tags like these that essentially *shouldn't* exist but that still need to be there so that the system can chug along...

Each indeed has only one meaning but what can be derived from them?  Not much.  Without a complimentary language relevant tag they mean nothing alone.

On the flip side, tags like the following actually could have meanings on their own accord and be discussed individually freed from the boundaries of any language.

- [if](/questions/tagged/if) (3,466)
- [for](/questions/tagged/for) (2,871) [foreach](/questions/tagged/foreach) (2,455) [while](/questions/tagged/while) (1,436)
- [function](/questions/tagged/function) (9,804)

IMO these tags are in place simply so that users will not get frustrated when not being allowed to tag their questions.

<sup>Numbers in brackets are questions containing the tag</sup>

The numbers speak for themselves - these tags **are** being used.  I think we can all agree thought that these tags add no real information to the tag list of a question.  If the code you post uses a while loop - I'm pretty sure we'll see it in the code.

<s>One last one for your viewing pleasure, my favorite -

[semicolon](/questions/tagged/semicolon) (75)</s>

I give you the pinnacle of ambiguity - [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) (2550).  Everything ranging from sed, linkedin, emacs, php, java, adobe... the list goes on...

Comment: Not to mention [tag:start] or [tag:stop]...

Comment: @bar - good ones :P

Answer (score 2):

They all refer to returning a value from a function.

Comment: Aaand, why is,it necessary?

Comment: I've seen worse tags than this.  It really only has one meaning.  Desserts aren't necessary, but I don't insist that they be banned at my favorite restaurant.

Comment: makes sense, leave well enough alone :/